# Is there any way to get rid of the tint on the jQuery accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I would like to have a completely white accordion header without that gray tint on the bottom half. Is there any way to accomplish that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

go to this page - http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and do any changes you want to CSS rules, then download your full CSS file and attach it to the document